# Google Play in WebView is not redirecting

Tags: android, webview, google-play, android-webview

I have link to Google Play that opens Chrome and automatically redirects to Play app on Android:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.raongames.growcastle

I wanted to redirect directly to Play app by rendering it on hidden WebView:

```
private fun openUrlForRedirection(linkToOffer: String) {
    loading = true
    webView.apply {
        setWebChromeClient(RedirectWebChromeClient(context))
        setWebViewClient(RedirectWebViewClient(::onRedirect, ::onRedirectionError))
        getSettings().apply {
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
            userAgentString = System.getProperty("http.agent")
            loadUrl(linkToOffer)
        }
    }
}

private fun onRedirect(str: String) {
    loading = false
    if (quest.pkg !in str) {
        installApp(quest.pkg)
    } else {
        openUrl(str)
    }
}

private fun onRedirectionError() {
    showAndLogError(UnknownError())
}

class RedirectWebChromeClient(val context: Context) : WebChromeClient() {

    override fun onJsAlert(webView: WebView, str: String, str2: String, jsResult: JsResult): Boolean {
        jsResult.cancel()
        return true
    }

    override fun onJsConfirm(webView: WebView, str: String, str2: String, jsResult: JsResult): Boolean {
        jsResult.cancel()
        return true
    }

    override fun onJsPrompt(webView: WebView, str: String, str2: String, str3: String, jsPromptResult: JsPromptResult): Boolean {
        jsPromptResult.cancel()
        return true
    }
}

class RedirectWebViewClient(
        private val onRedirect: (String) -> Unit,
        private val onError: () -> Unit
) : WebViewClient() {

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
        info("Finished")
    }

    override fun onReceivedError(webView: WebView, i: Int, str: String, str2: String) {
        if (i != -10) {
            onError()
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    override fun onReceivedError(webView: WebView, webResourceRequest: WebResourceRequest, webResourceError: WebResourceError) {
        onReceivedError(webView, webResourceError.errorCode, webResourceError.description.toString(), webResourceRequest.url.toString())
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = 21)
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView: WebView, webResourceRequest: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
        return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, webResourceRequest.url.toString())
    }

    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView: WebView, str: String): Boolean {
        onRedirect(str)
        return false
    }
}
```

But instead of redirection, I have Google Play webpage with button on bottom to redirect.

[image]

Comment: can you post an image of what you are getting ?

Comment: It is very small and in Polish, but it should be clear: Google Play in browser + "Open in Google Play app" floating in the bottom.

Comment: why you want to render it in your webview and then open the play store app ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
  final String appPackageName = activity.getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
    try {
    //if you have playstore it's will navigate to playstore
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    }
```

Comment: You are missing the point. I know I can redirect to Google Play using intent, but I need to do it using link. Later I will have there link with tracking.

Comment: how using link ? this is really clear, it launches an intent that goes to a certain link.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);

browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
// here do what you need with url
//for example use Intent to start google play 
//or simply call view.loadUrl(url); to prevent chrome from opening

         return(true);
         }
            });
```

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` returns true to indicate that
it is handling the event.

Answer (score 0):

Going via a webview is not recommended, and may even stop working at some point in the future. Going via an intent is definitely the recommended solution, and a much better experience for the user.

If you need a link with tracking, Google Play allows tracking of installs via the Play app using [Firebase analytics](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317522#enable).